# MySQL - How do I optimize appending field from table b to a query of table a

Tags: mysql, join

I know this has to be a fairly common issue, and I am sure the answer is readily available but I am not sure how to phrase my search so I have been forced to troubleshoot this on my own for the most part.

*Table A*

```
id | content_id | score
1  | 2          | 16
2  | 2          | 4
3  | 3          | 8
4  | 3          | 12
```

*Table B*

```
id | content
1  | "Content Goes Here"
2  | "Content Goes Here"
3  | "Content Goes Here"
```

**Objective:** SUM all scores from table A, group by the unique content_id and show the content associated with the id, ordered by the sum score.

**Current Working Query:**

```
SELECT a.content_id, b.content, SUM(a.score) AS sum 
FROM table_a a 
LEFT JOIN table_b b ON a.content_id = b.id 
GROUP BY a.content_id 
ORDER BY sum ASC;
```

**Problem:** As far as I can tell, with the way I have structured my query, the content is grabbed from table_b by looping through each record on table_a, checking for a record in table_b with an identical id, and grabbing the content field. The problem here is that in table_a there is nearly 500k+ records, and in table_b there is 112 records. Which means that potentially 500,000 x 112 cross table lookups/matches are being performed just to attached 112 unique content fields to a total of 112 results in the ending result set.

**HELP!:** How do I more efficiently append the 112 content fields from table_b to the 112 results produced by the query? I am guessing it has something to do with the query execution order, like somehow only looking for and appending the content field to the matched result row AFTER the sums are produced and it is narrowed down to only 112 records? Have studied the MySQL API and benchmarked various subqueries, several joins, and even tried playing with UNION. It is probably something abundandtly obvious to you guys, but my brain just can't get around it.

**FYI:** Like mentioned earlier, the query does work. The results are produced in about 8 to 10 seconds, and of course each subsequent query after that is immediate because of query caching. But for me, with how simple this is, I know that 8 seconds can at LEAST be cut in half. I just feel it deep down in my guts. Right deep down in my gutssss.

I hope this is concise enough, if I need to clarify or explain something better please let me know! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MySQL query optimiser only allows "[nested loop joins](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-internals.html)" ** These are the internal operators for how an INNER join is evaluated. Other RDBMS allow other kinds of JOINs which are more efficient.

However, in your case you can try this. Hopefully the optimiser will do the aggregate *before* the JOIN

```
SELECT
    a.content_id, b.content a.sum
FROM
    (
    SELECT content_id, SUM(score) AS sum 
    FROM table_a
    GROUP BY content_id
    ) a 
    JOIN table_b b ON a.content_id = b.id 
ORDER BY
    sum ASC;
```

In addition, if you don't want the results ordered you can use `ORDER BY NULL` which usually removes a `filesort` from the `EXPLAIN`. And of course, I assume that there are indexes on the 2 `content_id` columns (one primary key, one foreign key index)

Finally, I would also assume that an INNER JOIN will be enough: every `a.contentid` exists in `tableb`. If not, you are missing a foreign key and index on `a.contentid`

** It's getting better but [you need MariaDB](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/04/04/join-optimizations-in-mysql-5-6-and-mariadb-5-5/) or [MySQL 5.6](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimization-internals.html)

Comment: +1 for think-alike and for the `ORDER BY NULL` optimization :)

Comment: Yeah! In your case, the internal ORDER BY NULL will probably be ignored because of the OUTER one which contrdicts it. Other RDBMS won't allow an inner ORDER BY anyway

Comment: Interesting... i didn't knew that... i assume since the aggregation is done first the `ORDER BY NULL` will be used and then when the final result set is obtained the `ORDER BY asum` will be used

Comment: Inner order bys normally are used with LIMIT only. But MySQL docs don't say one way of the other. SQL Server will throw an error for example because it doesn't make sense

Comment: Brilliant, I love this solution. Exactly what I was looking for. And even more importantly, thank you for not simply posting a query without explaining why my query is inefficient, and why what you proposed is. And on the indices, unfortunately the db was built prior to my involvement, so there are absolutely no measures in place for data integrity. The contentid fields are primary keys, but no foreign key relationships between table_b and table_a, or any tables for that matter. *GASP* I know right? Thank you again, this is fantastic! I would +1 you even but apparently I need better rep haha

Answer (score 1):

This should be a little faster:

```
SELECT
    tmp.content_id,
    b.content,
    tmp.asum
FROM (
    SELECT 
        a.content_id, 
        SUM(a.score) AS asum 
    FROM 
        table_a a 
    GROUP BY 
        a.content_id 
    ORDER BY 
        NULL
) as tmp
LEFT JOIN table_b b 
    ON tmp.content_id = b.id 
ORDER BY
    tmp.asum ASC
```

You can use `EXPLAIN` to check the query execution plan for both queries when you want to benchmark them

Comment: I see this is something pretty similar to the answer I accepted. I haven't tested it, but I am sure it is still more efficient than mine. Thank you for taking the time to help me out! I really appreciate it. Had to accept his simply because he offered a more in-depth account of why the solution was more efficient. I would +1 you though, but I am a stackoverflow newb. Again, thanks though!